when flutter debug on real device 'ClientException with SocketException: Connection timed out' occurs
I'm on android studio. And configured a backend using spring boot. And that application run on localhost. For the emulator requests to the backend works fine. But on real device below error occurred.
ClientException with SocketException: Connection timed out (OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110), address = 10.0.2.2, port = 37500, uri=http://10.0.2.2:8080/login?email=akila&password=fuh
static const hostConnect = "http://10.0.2.2:8080";

static const login = "$hostConnect/login?email=";

var res = await http.get(
  Uri.parse("${API.login}${emailController.text.trim()}&password=${passwordController.text.trim()}"),
);

I want to request works on real device as well
